# Sequential reading of a text file with getc() and writing on a bin file with fwrite() not working as expected?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a simple (not really) program in C which utilizes files to generate a random list of ingredients which in future will be recipes.
I'm using text files and binary files with the help of all the related functions: getc(), fwrite(), fread(), ...

What I have tried is all shown in the code of two functions:

- int convert_txt_to_bin()
- int print_ingredient_file(path file_path)

I promise, they are not that complex.
Also sorry for the while closed with the break :)

ingredient

```
typedef struct {
    char name[32];  // The name of the ingredient: "Mela", "Fusilli", "Passata di pomodoro";
    int type;
} ingredient;
```

```
int convert_txt_to_bin()
{
    FILE *txt, *bin;
    ingredient tmp;
    int i = 0, records_written = 0;
    char c;
    tmp.type = 0;

    txt = fopen(file_list_fruits_txt, "r");
    bin = fopen(file_list_fruits_bin, "wb");

    if (txt && bin)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            tmp.name[i] = getc(txt);
            c = tmp.name[i];
            if (tmp.name[i] == '\n' || tmp.name[i] == EOF)
            {
                tmp.name[i] = '\0';
                fwrite(&tmp, sizeof(ingredient), 1, bin);
                while (i >= 0) tmp.name[i--] = '#';
                records_written++;
                i++;
                printf("Record written successfully\n");

                if (c == EOF) break;
            }
            else i++;
        }
        fclose(txt);
        fclose(bin);
        printf(".bin file written correctly\n%d records saved\n", records_written);
        return records_written;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ERROR: can't open file. Quitting...");
        system("PAUSE");
        fclose(txt);
        fclose(bin);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

```
int print_ingredient_file(path file_path)
{
    FILE* bin;
    ingredient tmp;
    int i = 0;

    bin = fopen(file_path, "rb");

    while (fread(&tmp, sizeof(ingredient), 1, bin))
        printf("Ingredient number #%d\n\tName = %s\n\tType = %d\n", i++, tmp.name, tmp.type);

    fclose(bin);
}
```

```
fruits.txt (it's in italian)
Mela
Banana
Pera
Kiwi
Pesca
Albicocca
Mandarino
Uva
Ciliegia
Lampone
Fragola
Mora
Mirtillo
Fico
Nespola
Caco
Anguria
Melone
Melograno
Arancia
Mango
```

```
fruits.bin
```

19 out of 21 fruits are successfully recorded.
I don't understand why Pera (pear) and Banana (guess what) are not saved correctly and give problems with the output.

Output to stdout:

```
Record written successfully
Record written successfully
Record written successfully
Record written successfully
Record written successfully
Record written successfully
Record written successfully
Record written successfully
Record written successfully
Record written successfully
Record written successfully
Record written successfully
Record written successfully
Record written successfully
Record written successfully
Record written successfully
Record written successfully
Record written successfully
Record written successfully
.bin file written correctly
19 records saved
Ingredient number #0    <------------------------------ Perana ???
Perana  Name = Mela
        Type = 0
Ingredient number #1
        Name = Kiwi
        Type = 0
Ingredient number #2
        Name = Pesca
        Type = 0
Ingredient number #3
        Name = Albicocca
        Type = 0
Ingredient number #4
        Name = Mandarino
        Type = 0
Ingredient number #5
        Name = Uva
        Type = 0
Ingredient number #6
        Name = Ciliegia
        Type = 0
Ingredient number #7
        Name = Lampone
        Type = 0
Ingredient number #8
        Name = Fragola
        Type = 0
Ingredient number #9
        Name = Mora
        Type = 0
Ingredient number #10
        Name = Mirtillo
        Type = 0
Ingredient number #11
        Name = Fico
        Type = 0
Ingredient number #12
        Name = Nespola
        Type = 0
Ingredient number #13
        Name = Caco
        Type = 0
Ingredient number #14
        Name = Anguria
        Type = 0
Ingredient number #15
        Name = Melone
        Type = 0
Ingredient number #16
        Name = Melograno
        Type = 0
Ingredient number #17
        Name = Arancia
        Type = 0
Ingredient number #18
        Name = Mango
        Type = 0
Premere un tasto per continuare . . .
```

Comment: Post def of `ingredient`, a [mcve]

Comment: Unfortunately your code is very elaborate, which makes it not [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) enough :(

Comment: OT: regarding: `txt = fopen(file_list_fruits_txt, "r");` and `bin = fopen(file_list_fruits_bin, "wb");`  When calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the assure the operation was successful.   If not successful (returned value is NULL) then call `perror( "your error message" );` to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `typedef struct {
    char name[32];  
    int type;
} ingredient;`   always use a 'tag' name on a struct definition as the 'tag' name is what most debuggers use to be able to display the individual fields of the struct

Comment: the function: `getc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`,  The macro: `EOF` is an `int`, not a `char`.  so this statement: `if (c == EOF) break;` and this statement: `if (tmp.name[i] == '\n' || tmp.name[i] == EOF)` will (most likely) fail when checking for `EOF`

Comment: in the struct `ingredient`, the field: `type` is not initialized, so contains what ever trash happened to be in the stack at the location of the struct.  Writing that uninitialized data to the file is undefined behavior.  Your compiler should have told you about this

Comment: regarding: `txt = fopen(file_list_fruits_txt, "r");
    bin = fopen(file_list_fruits_bin, "wb");

    if (txt && bin)`  and `else
    {
        printf("ERROR: can't open file. Quitting...");
        system("PAUSE");
        fclose(txt);
        fclose(bin);`  1) Check each result of a call to `fopen()` separately   2) do not call `fclose()` on a file pointer that was never successfully opened

Comment: OT: when calling `fread()` and/or `fwrite()`  always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: @user3629249 Hey thank you a lot, really :) 

So you suggest:

1) Check all the NULL returns
2) Add a tag to the struct
3) Use a int var to check for EOF
4) Initialize the struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some good suggestions in the comments, but it seems most likely that the problem you are reporting is not a programming issue so much as a problem with your data file. The superposition of `Banana` and `Pera` over the line which prints `Mera` strongly suggests that the first two lines in your file are not correctly terminated with a newline character, but rather with a carriage return.

I honestly don't know how this might occur these days. Twenty years ago, Apple's operating system used CR line endings, but that changed when Apple rebased their OS on FreeBSD. Windows still uses a two-character CR-LF sequence to indicate newline, but since that includes a `\n`, it should not lead to this particular problem.

So all I can suggest is that you examine your input file with a hex editor (or just look at it with `hd`) and see what the character code(s) at the end of the lines are.

Comment: I solved it, after the "bad lines" there was only a 0D hex value, or a CR. On the other hand, at the correct lines there was a CRLF sequence.

Comment: I had to manually add a LF value, I don't know how it was removed or never added. Maybe because I opened with Notepad++, dunno, really